# Render big list into table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a big list which I am grouping into a size of 500 and then rendering them one at a time to client on demand. I am using the following Java script code to render the list into table.

```js
var counter;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });

  $('#button').click(function() {
    alert(table.rows('.selected').data().length + ' row(s) selected');
  });
});

function getData(submit) {
  var pointer;
  var msg = "";
  var company = "";

  if (submit == 1) {
    //On click of get more
    counter += 500;
    pointer = counter;
   
  } else {
    //On load
    counter = 500;
    pointer = 500;
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/biz/getListOfFreeMembers",
    data: {
      limit: pointer
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
        var t = $('#example').DataTable();
        t.row.add([
          obj.companyName,
          obj.mobileNo,
          obj.companyWebsite,
          obj.firstName,
          obj.address,
          obj.createDate
        ]).draw();
      });
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert("error" + e.Message);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="example" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Company Name</th>
          <th>Mobile Number</th>
          <th>Website</th>
          <th>Person Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Date of Creation</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="list_of_users">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:getData('1')">Get more data</a>
```

The table is rendering correctly for the first time, but when I click the Get more data link, the new set of data is not appending to the existing set, instead the new set is getting displayed first and then the old set and so on for each click of get more data. Please suggest a way for appending the new data set to the old one in the table. Thank you.

Comment: Note there is a *"code tidy"* button right in the snippet editor you used to insert the code

Comment: because the counter does not exist on the second run .. put the counter outside the function

Comment: The count does exist on second run and all runs after that. It is a global variable(and outside the function too.) I just need to append the new list to the old one. Otherwise it is working fine.

Comment: You are re-initializing plugin each time. Only initialize it once so it maintains state when you add new data

Comment: What should be the solution then?

Comment: Store your `t` ... if it's not defined then initalize , if not just add. Or use a flag to indicate it has been initialized

Comment: It is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. [(check this codePen)](http://codepen.io/mastersmind/full/MmORzO)

- May be you are missing, that Page Numbers are increasing (meaning new data is going on the next pages)
- Or May be your service is not responding the data (Check the Network Console)

```js
var counter=0;
var t=null;
var url = 'tableData';
$(document).ready(function() {
  t = $('#example').DataTable();
  t
    .column( '0:visible' )
    .order( '' )
    .draw();
  
  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });

  $('#button').click(function() {
    alert(t.rows('.selected').data().length + ' row(s) selected');
  });

  
getData();  
});

function getData(submit) {
  $('#loading').show();
  var pointer=0;
  var msg = "";
  var company = "";

  if (submit == 1) {
    //On click of get more
    counter += 500;
    pointer = counter;

    url = 'tableData2';

  } else {
    //On load
    counter = 500;
    pointer = 500;

    url = 'tableData';
  }


  $.ajax({
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://demo2315600.mockable.io/" + url,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#loading').hide();
      //alert('asd');
      $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
        t.row.add([
          obj.companyName,
          obj.mobileNo,
          obj.companyWebsite,
          obj.firstName,
          obj.address,
          obj.createDate
        ]).draw();
      });
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert("error" + e.Message);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="example" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Company Name</th>
          <th>Mobile Number</th>
          <th>Website</th>
          <th>Person Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Date of Creation</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="list_of_users">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:getData('1')">Get more data</a>

<span id="loading" style="display:none;">pleas wait Load Data</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am getting the same results as I was getting before after trying your modifications. The new list should append the existing list, but instead it is getting created at the beginning and then the old list follows.

Comment: Ok now i got ur problem. Its all about sorting no problem with adding new rows. New Rows add at the end but it show depending on ur sorted column.

Comment: Thank you very much, How do I avoid sorting of that column?

Comment: t = $('#example').DataTable();
  t
    .column( '0:visible' )
    .order( '' )
    .draw();

Comment: It is now sorting in Descending order, can you please update the java script in your above snippet as to where I need to add the  t .column( '0:visible' ) .order( '' ) .draw();

Comment: It is now solved I added this code  $('#example').DataTable( {
        
        "ordering": false,
        
    } ); On document on load method. Thank you mastermind for your help.